# Is there any reason why System.Reactive.Unit wasn't called System.Reactive.Void?

Tags: system.reactive

Mainly, I'm curious.

We have an object called `Unit` in our codebase - which represents a component for a bridge or a road. In our case, it can be ambiguous to see ReactiveUI Commands with `Unit` as one of the Generics in a declaration.

Even in this [old documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh211727%28v%3Dvs.103%29) (Google doesn't point me in the direction of the current documentation - where ever that is), it says:

> "Represents void."

So now I'm wondering, is there any meaning behind the term `Unit`. How come they didn't just call it `System.Reactive.Void`?

Comment: Trivia: there is a type already called `System.Void`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.void

Comment: Maybe *that's* why they didn't use `Void`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To quote Wikipedia (which also gives examples of other languages using the same name)

> [a unit type is a type that allows only one value (and thus can hold no information).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type)

In this case the value is `Unit.Default`.

Comment: Right, so the term is derived from a mathematical concept! `void` is also a Unit, but can't be used as an Object - hence the new class `System.Reactive.Unit`

Comment: So now I see the naming dilemma -  do you call it `Void` and create confusion between the lowercase cousin, or give it a different name (like `Unit`) and risk confusing someone (like me)